# What GnuPG files need backing up?

Tags: gnupg, backup

Which GnuPG files (the ones typically under `~/.gnupg/`) do I need?

I have a script for backing up "private information" that tars it all up and password protects it using `openssl` with AES256. Is this method "secure"?

Right now, it just grabs all of `~/.gnupg`. I am about to start a clean installation and don't want to lose anything that can't be gotten back.

Answer (score 3):

### Backing up GnuPG

> Which GPG files (the ones typically under `~/.gnupg/`) do I need?

#### Relevant files

A "usual" GnuPG home directory (`~/.gnupg` on Linux and other unixoid systems, a similar path on Windows) contains following information for most users:

- public key ring `pubring.gpg`, storing the public keys you fetched (for verifying other signatures, and encrypting information/messages to other users)
- private key ring `secring.gpg`, storing your own private keys (this one is merged with the public key ring starting from GnuPG 2.1)
- trust information `trustdb.gpg` (different to certifications/signatures on other keys, you also have to issue trust to verify keys throughout the web of trust)
- configuration `gpg.conf` and possible `gpg-agent.conf`

#### What needs to be backed up

While generally public keys can be recovered from the key servers, the private keys are very important to back up; also have a revocation certificate at hand! Trust information is also private and not shared through key servers. Configuration is something of debatable importance, but you might also prefer not losing your configured preferences (as it's a hassle to redo that).

In the end, I simply put the whole `~/.gnupg` directory in my backup, together with pretty much everything else in my home directory. I have a separate, QR-encoded (unencrypted) paper copy of my revocation certificate stored at another place, because worst thing that might happen is somebody uses it to revoke my primary key, but I definitely do *not* want to have an OpenPGP key with certifications out of my control on the key servers.

#### Official recommendations

`man gpg` recommends to backup your public key ring, private key ring (if using GnuPG pre 2.1) and finally *exporting* your trust database instead of backing up the database file (running `gpg --export-ownertrust`). You might be able to do so using some pre-backup script, I decided to simply backup the whole GnuPG directory and not care about the individual files.

### Encrypting your backup

> I have a script for backing up "private information" that tars it all up and password protects it using openssl with AES256. Is this method "secure"?

AES256 is considered secure and can also be used with OpenPGP. Be sure not to encrypt it with your own public/private key pair only stored on your machine and in the (encrypted) backup, of course. GnuPG `--symmetric` encryption with appropriate parameters might also be fine for that purpose, but using OpenSSL provides equivalent security.

### Backups while resetting your computer

> Right now, it just grabs all of `~/.gnupg`. I am about to start a clean installation and don't want to lose anything that can't be gotten back.

Using your backup to migrate to a new installation seems not the most reasonable thing to do. You're performing administration tasks out of "daily schedule", which results in increased probability of failures while doing so; at the same time you're giving up your primary copy of your data and trust that everything in your second copy is fine.

If you haven't got a spare disk for your primary data (or even better, a complete image of your old setup that you keep around for a while) that is *not* your backup, buy one. They're cheap, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct, you save the right directory and with a secure method.

Check with `openssl version` you are using a safe version.

Put the `openssl` crypted repository on another physical media than the one hosting your keyrings in `~/.gnupg`, ex. an USB key you verified, unmount and put in a closed drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely *need* to backup your private key rings.

You probably *want* to backup your public key rings.

Everything else *should*, strictly speaking, be optional.

That said, those files tend to be so small (on the order of a few megabytes or less) that these days **there really is no benefit to not backing up everything** in ~/.gnupg. Doing so will ensure that you don't forget something that later turns out to be important.

I would also point out that OpenSSL exposes raw crypto primitives. If you don't know exactly what you are doing, there is a fairly high risk of inadvertantly introducing problems by using them directly. If you don't have some specific reason for doing it this way, consider just using GnuPG itself to encrypt the archive. Something like `tar cf - dir | gpg ...` should be a good start (and also avoids creating an intermediate file on disk).